# Copy constructor on "Observer pattern"

Tags: c++

Suppose we a design pattern similar to this one:

```
#include <set>

class Receiver;

class Transmitter {
public:
   Transmitter() = default;

   virtual ~Transmitter() { 
      for(auto recv : m_receivers){
         recv->setSource(nullptr);
      }
   }

   const std::set<Receiver*> getReceivers(){
      return m_receivers;
   }
private:
   std::set<Receiver*> m_receivers;
};

class Receiver {
public:
   Receiver() = default;
   Receiver(const Receiver& other){
      setTransmitter(other.m_trans);
   }
   ~virtual ~Receiver(){
      setTransmitter(nullptr);
   }

   void setTransmitter(Transmitter* tr){
      if(m_trans) m_trans->m_recv.erase(this)
      m_trans=tr;
      if(m_trans) m_trans->m_recv.insert(this)
   }
private:
   Transmitter* m_trans = nullptr;
};
```

It seems to be a [Observer pattern](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Design_Patterns#Observer): Two classes which have a relationship of 1:M and both hold references to one another.

Now imagine that we want to make them compatible with `std::vector` or any other similar `std` containers. Therefore it needs to be copy construct-able (or move-able).

The `Receiver` can be copy-able (as shown in the code above), however, the problem arises with the transmitter. I have thought about different alternatives, but I can't decide what to do:

- Should the copy constructor behave as the default constructor or should it be deleted?
- Should I define a move constructor which steals receivers from the other?
- Or should I simply ban copy and move initialization? (no solution to the problem)

  There is a [similar question in stack overflow about this problem in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306276/copying-listeners-observers-in-a-copy-constructor). However answer might change for C++

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by "making them compatible with `std::vector`..." and by "the problem arising with the transmitter"?

Comment: NVM. Got what you meant after reading Artyer's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A move constructor would be appropriate:

```cpp
Transmitter(Transmitter&& other) noexcept : m_receivers(std::move(other.m_receivers)) {
   for (auto recv : m_receivers) {
       recv->m_trans = this;
   }
}
```

A move works because after the move, the new object should be equivalent to the moved-from object, so from the observers' point of view, the transmitter hasn't changed.

The reason this is different from Java is that Java doesn't have move constructors so there's no (easy) way to express "steal the observers/resources".

Comment: It's probably best to explicitly delete copying and add a move assignment operator too.